# How to call a function from an external .c file using a .h file in C?

Tags: c, function, file, call, external

I'm having some trouble calling a external function that is defined in an external `.c` file.

My main file (`main.c`) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main () {

int a = 100;
int b = 200;
int ret;

ret = maximo(a, b);

printf( "Max value is : %d\n", ret );

return 0;
}
```

I use a `.h` file called `header.h` to declare the funtion `maximo()`. The `header.h` file is:

```
int maximo(int num1, int num2);
```

And in another `.c` file, I have the definition of the funtion `maximo()`. The `maximo.c`file is:

```
int maximo(int num1, int num2) {

int result;

if (num1 > num2)
   result = num1;
else
   result = num2;

return result;
}
```

The codes I presented above are the whole code of my files. The `header.h` file is only that one line. And I did'n put any `#include`in the `maximo.c` file.

I don't kwon if it is missing anything, because, as you can see, I am an beginner in programming.

The errors I'm having are:

```
undefined reference to 'maximo'
error: 1d returned 1 exit status
```

I tried putting the `maximo.c` code inside the `header.h` file and it works fine, but that is not what I need.

During my searches I read some things about compiling both `.c`codes together so they turn into `.o` files and then the `.h` file can link them properly, but I don't know how to do that.

So if anyone could help me, I would be extremely grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you compile the code?

Comment: How do you *build* your program? You need to build with the source file containing the `maximo` function of course, or the object file generated from that source file.

Comment: Your immediate problem is a linking error. You need to specify both your program and the separate file on the linking command line.

Comment: What did your C book say?

Comment: I use Code::Blocks to run the codes.

Answer (score 6):

You will also need to `#include "header.h"` in your `maximo.c` file. Don't forget include guards in your header file too:

```
#ifndef MAXIMO_H
#define MAXIMO_H

int maximo(int num1, int num2);

#endif
```

P.S. would recommend you change the "header.h" to "maximo.h".

Your command line should read:

```
gcc main.c maximo.c -o "filename"
```